# Does std::move result in slicing?

Tags: c++, dynamic, std, move-semantics, object-slicing

For example, in

```
unique_ptr<Derived> = new deriv;
std::vector<unique_ptr<Base>>.push_back(std::move(deriv));
```

will deriv be sliced to type `unique_ptr<Base>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No slicing will occur; the `unique_ptr<Base>` will own the pointer to the `Derived` object.

A `unique_ptr` to a derived class can be implicitly converted to a `unique_ptr` to a base class.

Answer (score 2):

(your example doesn't compile in the current edit, I'm just going to assume what your intent was)

No, it doesn't. Slicing refers to copying Derived objects into a Base object, not a Derived pointer into a Base pointer (here, the unique_ptr is a red herring).

This results in slicing:

```
class a { };

class b : public a { };

void foo(a myvar) { };

int main()
{
    b myb;
    foo(myb);
}
```

This does not:

```
class a { };

class b : public a { };

void foo(a* myvar) { };

int main()
{
    b myb;
    foo(&myb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any slicing that could occur, would occur on the element type of the container.  Objects contained indirectly are not affected.